# New Glenn Rocket Assembly: Horizontal or Vertical?

Tags: blue-origin, new-glenn, vehicle-assembly-building

Saturn V was assembled vertically. Falcon 9 is assembled horizontally. Curious if New Glenn will follow Saturn V or Falcon 9 in its assembly approach. Falcon's crawler erector would seem a bigger challenge on a rocket nearly the size of Saturn V... but maybe they'll assemble New Glenn Horizontally nevertheless?

Comment: Blue origin does seem to be a bit more traditional so I’d assume they’d stack vertically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blue Origin's manufacturing facility in Florida is already built and built *horizontally* for New Glenn:

[image: Blue Origin Facility Florida]

Also, their launch pad SLC-36 has what looks like a horizontal hangar (similar to what Space-X has at LC-39A):

[image: SLC-36 Facility]

Where the blue rectangle is the approximate horizontal footprint of the New Glenn full stack (~95m x 7 m), imagery from Feb. 2020.

As they do not seem to have a vertical facility (hard to hide a ~100m tall building on the Florida coast) I think it is safe to conclude that they will horizontal integrate the rocket *somewhere*.

https://www.blueorigin.com/news/new-glenns-progress-towards-maiden-flight

https://www.blueorigin.com/new-glenn/

Comment: @OrganicMarble yes they are two different facilities, I will make that clearer

Comment: @OrganicMarble I do not know, I will remove reference to integration at manufacturing facility